# Custom \bonusqformat in exam class not level with question text

Tags: exam

I am creating a set of problems, with the bonus problems starred with an *, but when I use `\bonusqformat` to customize the mark, it pushes the text onto a new line. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

MWE

```
\documentclass{exam}

\bonusqformat{\thequestion *.}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\bonusquestion This is a question.

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: This is the default behavior of `exam`. The question title (typeset according to `\qformat` or `\bonusqformat`) is on a line by itself and the question text is below it.

Comment: I understand this is the default behaviour, I'm more looking for a way to overcome it, whilst still having the starred questions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @egreg, prompted me to look elsewhere for the answer! Posted it below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that because of the default behaviour of `\bonusqformat` (pointed out by egreg), it is easier to achieve this effect by the following code in the preamble:

```
\newcommand\bonusquestionlabel{\thequestion{}*.}
\makeatletter
\def\question@number{%
  \if@bonus
    \if@bonusqformat
      \makebox[\hsize][s]{\@bonusquestionformat}\hskip-\labelsep
    \else
      \bonusquestionlabel
    \fi
  \else
    \if@qformat
      \makebox[\hsize][s]{\@questionformat}\hskip-\labelsep
    \else
      \questionlabel
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This code redefines the question label for bonus questions and makes a new label for them.

Result from the MWE with the extra code in the preamble
[image: MWE working!]